# JSON parsing with OPENJSON in SQL Server 2012

Tags: json, sql-server

I have a JSON format column in one of the tables. Format is as shown in the screenshot below. Can anyone please help me to how to read `_$dynProp` values? It is an arraylist within an array.

I am using SQL Server 2012 and I think only OPENJSON can be used to read files.

[image: JSON data format]

Thank you
Amir

Comment: I tried to do below but last col returns null.                                                              Select * FROM OPENJSON (@JSON, '$.ctx."0760" ')

       WITH (          
                employerName varchar(250) '$.employerName'    
               ,employmentNatureEnumID varchar(250) '$.employmentNatureEnumID'
      --,[_$dynProp] nvarchar(max) as JSON
      ,valuesjson nvarchar(max) '$.ctx."0760"."_$dynProp"' as JSON
        )

Comment: `OPENJSON` is a feature available in SQL Server **2016** and newer - not available in 2012, unfortunately

Comment: We need compatibility 13 to execute openjson. i have brought one node data in col but can;t get into another arraylist in same node. Below query return key and value but i need its arraylist as a seperate row or col which ever is possible.                                                                  Select * FROM OPENJSON (@JSON, '$.ctx."0760"')